# Page redirection in sharepoint 2010 webpart(sandboxed solution) using c# code is it possible?

Tags: redirect, sharepoint-2010, sandbox, office365

I am using a sandboxed solution (sharepoint 2010 project is on office 365 hence using sandboxed solution) and want to go from one page to another on a button click event. This is achieved by javascript but the operations in the click event are not being performed.

For example, I assign the javascript on page load to the desired event then the event performs the redirection without going into the code which is inside the event.

The javascript used for redirection is :

```
string redirectURL = "http://ksreejit:32512/sites/SplTeam/Pages/QuizMasterDashboard.aspx";
btnCancel.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:{window.location='" + redirectURL + "';return false;}");
```

And the event code is:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (ViewState["QuestionID"].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                SaveDetails(ViewState["QuestionID"].ToString());
                foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls)
                {
                    contrl.Visible = false;
                }

            } 
            else
            {
                SaveDetails();
                foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls)
                {
                    contrl.Visible = false;
                }

            }
            Label lblMessage = new Label();
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "The Question is successfully saved and sent to reviewer for reviewing. Thanks for uploading.";

   }
```

As you can see the redirection works for btnCancel successfully. I have not assigned it for btnSubmit cos it will then only redirect and will not go to the above specified code.Tried microsoft help they were also clueless.Answers will be appreciated.the project requirement has been modified. long time no answers please check more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its javascript then break open the browser dev toolbar and you will see exactly whats going on.

Comment: no javascript isnt the problem

Answer (score 6):

Add this code in your button click

```
string redirectURL = "http://ksreejit:32512/sites/SplTeam/Pages/QuizMasterDashboard.aspx";
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script>window.location.href='" + redirectURL + "';</script>"));
```

Comment: will check this and let you know

Comment: that won't work, you'll have to put <script></script> tag around the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

For your btnSubmit button, don't add the attribute like you did for your btnCancel.
And then simply add a `Response.Redirect(...);` in your event method.

```
... lblMessage.Text = "The Question is successfully saved and sent to reviewer for reviewing. Thanks for uploading.";

Response.Redirect("http://ksreejit:32512/sites/SplTeam/Pages/QuizMasterDashboard.aspx");
```

Comment: sorry frnd tried that that do not work on office 365 that's another problem.

Comment: @Sreejit You cannot to do a server side redirect in a sandboxed solution. It is explicitly disabled. You'll have to do have some sort of javascript work around.

Comment: yes that is what i did the code above(javascript) works as an attribute to the button click event but do not perform the code that the event contain. This redirection works fine when you do not have to do anything in the event.